# why are AMD CPU's generally slower then comparable intel CPU's, despite being clocked higher?

Tags: cpu, speed

Generally, AMD processors are slower then comparable Intel procesors, despite being clocked higher. A friends intel i7 is clocked at 3.2GHz, my AMD  phenom is clocked at 3.4GHz. Both are quad cores, yet his CPU outperforms mine. Why is that?

Comment: I challenge the premise. There's a lot more at play here than just vendor. In this case, though, hyperthreading may play a big part in it.

Comment: "Out performs" it how?  Based on what?

Comment: Certainly not in the P4 NetBurst vs AthlonXP  days.  There are too many variables for this answer.  This will help:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megahertz_myth

Comment: @techie007 in nearly all benchmarks.

Comment: @paradroid interesting article. And excuse me for the triple post. Phone is doing weird.

Comment: Interesting, it used to be the opposite - AMD significantly outperformed Intel.  That's why they marketed their, e.g. 1.3GHz chips as "1600+", they claimed their 1.3GHz performance at least as good as an Intel 1.6GHz.

Comment: The Athlon II X3 is still the value king among gaming CPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because clock speed has very little to do with it - My 6+ year old (I think it is 6 now!) P4 3.0ghz wouldn't remotely stand up to a Core I3 rated at 2Ghz, it would probably be 4-6x slower on raw number crunching, and due to other improvements/sub routines built in, other tasks will also most likely be slower.

AMD machines may have less performance, but, they also cost less - so - it is all swings and roundabouts!

For true comparison, I recommend [looking here](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php).

Comment: I do not know about the reliability of CPU Benchmarks from PassMark, but at least their Video Benchmarks are completely made up.

Comment: Ironically, 10 years ago AMD was trying very, very hard to convince people this was the case while their CPU's were outperforming Intel CPUs clocked much higher. Now the shoe is on the other foot and AMD is playing catch-up.